# How do banned accounts work ... memory wise? i.e Roblox, Fortnite, etc

Tags: memory, storage, server-side

I can't find a stack where I can ask this question however it's related to servers, and storage.

I know how game admins can simply unban an account.
I also know how when you get your account banned, it doesn't get deleted (which would help the servers) But I also don't understand the concept of getting your account banned.
I understand that you can't access your account anymore however **its still there.**

So the account itself, is it reduced in memory or is it just a message saying your account is banned?

Comment: To keep it simple: Yes, you can assume it is just a message saying your account is banned.

Answer (score 1):

All the information is saved in a database. The idea is soft deletion. The table will contain a column that says if it's banned or not. Then, when the server and client are authenticating with each other, if the client attempts to access things without permission, the server will reject it. The data associated with the account isn't deleted, it's just unusable since the server will reject auth credentials.

Comment: So there's no memory reducement of all? It's just unusable?

Comment: @crash15 I'm not sure what you mean. But ultimately nothing is deleted or removed, so no. It's one of the niceties about soft-deleting items in a database. None of the data is actually deleted so it can be reinstated easily and the information can be kept for auditing purposes and seeing why it was banned, or any other reason one would keep records of the user.